In Catholicism, what is the significance of Mary being κεχαριτωμένη in Luke 1:28?
Luke 1:28:

Καὶ [And] εἰσελθὼν [having entered] πρὸς [to] αὐτὴν [her] εἶπεν [he said], Χαῖρε [Greetings], κεχαριτωμένη [having been graced/highly favored], ὁ [the] Κύριος [Lord] μετὰ [with] σοῦ [you].

NIV:

The angel went to her [Mary] and said, ‘Greetings, you who are highly favored! The Lord is with you.’

While many people in the NT are considered to have "χάρις" [grace], Mary is the only person described as being "κεχαριτωμένη" [having been graced/highly favored].
Do Catholics attach any particular significance to this choice of words in Luke?
I will accept answers from the writing of the church itself, and from Catholic apologists.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In Catholicism, what is the significance of Mary beingκεχαριτωμένη in Luke 1:28?
The Greek word “kecharitōmenē” has no real equivalent meaning in our English language. We are thus divided into basically two manners of Catholic thought as how to translate this Greek term employed by St. Luke. The translation as favoured one is not an altogether wrong interpretation or translation, it is simply not strong. The translation as ”full of grace” is clearly stronger and is is at odds with the Ecumenical Movements of our day. This is also the manner in which St. Jerome translated this term into his Latin Vulgate.

Tradition as well as writings of the early Church fathers like St. Irenaeus, St. Jerome, Tertullian, Origen, Eusebius of Caesarea and the Muratorian canon all identified Luke as the author of one of the synoptic gospels. However, scripture scholars are not in agreement as to the date of the authorship of the gospel of Luke; some scholars say that it was written in A.D. 70 and others in A.D. 62.
Chaire! Kecharitōmenē: Hail Favoured one or Full of Grace?
Let us turn our attention to the gospel of Luke particularly in Luke 1:28 where it says in Greek “Chaire! kecharitōmenē”. The Greek word “kecharitōmenē” has no English equivalent that is why translating this in our modern language is somehow problematic. There are currently two schools of thought in the translation of the Greek word “Kecharitomene”.
In order to render this passage in English, scripture scholars use the definition of the Greek word “kecharitōmenē” as their basis for translating it. Kecharitomene is derived from the Greek word “Charito” which means grace, and by definition grace means “favor”, hence the translation “Hail, favoured one”.
Though this translation is not inherently wrong, yet, it only speaks of Mary as just being favoured for being chosen as the bearer of the son of God. According to New Testament scholar Fr. Raymond Brown, translating Luke 1:28 to “full of grace” is a strong one and would not appeal to the sensibilities of the ecumenical movement.
From the earliest days of Christianity Luke 1:28 is always translated as full of grace, in A.D. 383 St. Jerome translated the Greek New Testament in Latin the lingua franca of the people. In his translation, Luke 1:28 is translated as “gratia plena” in which the English equivalent is “Full of grace”. Basing itself on the Latin vulgate the Douay-Rheims version of the English bible also translated it to “full of grace.“
They preferred this translation of the Greek word kecharitōmenē because it not only describes the blessed virgin Mary as being favoured for being chosen to bear the son of God but also manifests the transformative power of grace. When elucidating its teaching about the blessed virgin Mary the Church always uses the translation “full of grace” in its documents.
Kecharitōmenē: A transformative grace
Grammatically, “kecharitōmenē” is the perfect passive participle of the Greek word “charito” [grace] which describes an action that began in the past and continues to have its effect in the present. When applied to the blessed virgin Mary it indicates that she was transformed by grace and this grace remains in her and continues to have its effect perpetually. Kecharitōmenē is a causative verb in Greek which means it connotes a transformation to the one acted upon; in this case Mary is the one that is being acted upon by the causative verb kecharitomene. Luke’s use of the causative verb in Luke chapter 2 indicates that he sees Mary not just a favoured being who will bear the Son of God but someone who was transformed and affected by grace. When the angel Gabriel called Mary the “kecharitōmenē” in Luke 1:28, the transformative and saving power of grace already happened to Mary even before the annunciation. - The Marian Interpretation of Luke 1:28 “Chaire! Kecharitōmenē

Here follows how the Catholic apologist Andrew M. Greenwell explains things:

The word that Luke uses - κεχαριτωμένη, kecharitomene - appears to have been crafted out of thin air, appearing into the Greek vocabulary as unexpectedly as the Angel Gabriel appeared to Mary and as silently as the Word became Flesh.  It was the word for the moment.
The word is used nowhere else in the Scriptures or in secular Greek literature. The technical name for such a novel, unique word is hapax legomenon.  Hapax legomenon--which comes to us from Greek--means "expressed once."
This sort of word is sometimes also referred to as a nonce word.  In this case, it is a one-of-a-kind word for a one-of-a-kind person in a one-of-a-kind situation.  No one else in human history is κεχαριτωμένη (kecharitomene).
Though a nonce word, it is not nonsensical.  Grammatically, the word kecharitomene is the feminine present perfect passive voice participle of a verb, specifically, the Greek verb χαριτόω (charitóō).  In the passive voice, the verb means to have been made graceful, to have been endowed with grace.
The word that Luke uses--κεχαριτωμένη, kecharitomene - appears to have been crafted out of thin air, appearing into the Greek vocabulary as unexpectedly as the Angel Gabriel appeared to Mary and as silently as the Word became Flesh.  It was the word for the moment.
The word is used nowhere else in the Scriptures or in secular Greek literature.  The technical name for such a novel, unique word is hapax legomenon.  Hapax legomenon--which comes to us from Greek--means "expressed once."
This sort of word is sometimes also referred to as a nonce word.  In this case, it is a one-of-a-kind word for a one-of-a-kind person in a one-of-a-kind situation.  No one else in human history is κεχαριτωμένη (kecharitomene).
Though a nonce word, it is not nonsensical.  Grammatically, the word kecharitomene is the feminine present perfect passive voice participle of a verb, specifically, the Greek verb χαριτόω (charitóō).  In the passive voice, the verb means to have been made graceful, to have been endowed with grace.
In his On Nature and Grace, St. Augustine--the expounder par excellence of the doctrine of original sin--explains Mary's unique situation in this manner: "An abundance of grace (plus gratiae) was conferred on her, who merited to conceive and bear Him of whom we know was without sin."  In other words, there is a parallelism between the absence of original sin in Mary (through grace), and the absence of sin (by necessity) in Christ.
Medieval theologians described it this way.  They saw Mary's "fullness of grace" (plenitudo gratiae) as something between the "fullness of grace" that was unique to Christ (cf. John 1:4) and the "fullness of grace" that might be found in the Holy Angels and the Saints (cf. Acts 6:8).  This special and unique condition of Mary was described as plenitudo summae abundantiae (a plenary fullness of abundance of grace) or a plenitudo redundantiae (plenary redoundingness of grace).
This unique condition expounded and developed by the Medieval theologians in their cumbruous is precise Latin phrases is implied in the unique germ of a Greek word kecharitomene.
Clearly, the Golden-and-Greek-tongued Father of the Church, St. John Chrysostom understood the word Kecharitomene to be nominal, titular, official, personal to Mary.  And he is our sure guide.  How else can we explain this virtual explosion of praise to Mary--not in the name of Mary-but in her other God-given name--Kecharitomene--in one of his Christmas Day sermons?
Hail, Kecharitomene, unreaped land of heavenly grain.
Hail, Kecharitomene, virgin mother, true and unfailing vine.
Hail, Kecharitomene, faultless one carrying the immutable divinity.
Hail, Kecharitomene, spacious room for the uncontainable nature.
Hail, Kecharitomene, new bride of a widowed world and incorrupt offspring.
Hail, Kecharitomene, weaving as creature a crown not made by hands.
Hail, Kecharitomene, habitation of holy fire.
Hail, Kecharitomene, return of the fugitive world.
Hail, Kecharitomene, lavish nourisher for the hungry creation.
Hail, Kecharitomene, interminable grace of the holy virgin.
Hail, Kecharitomene, lampstand adorned with all virtue and with inextinguishable
light brighter than even the sun.
Hail, Kecharitomene, challenger of spirits.
Hail, Kecharitomene, wise bearer of spiritual glory.
Hail, Kecharitomene, golden urn, contaning heavenly manna.
Hail, Kecharitomene, dispensing sweet drink ever flowing to fill those who are thirsty.
Hail, Kecharitomene, spiritual sea who holds Christ, the heavenly pearl.
Hail, Kecharitomene, splendor of heaven, having the one uncontained by the heavens in herself, God confined and unconfined.
Hail, Kecharitomene, pillar of cloud, containing God, and guiding Israel in the wilderness."

Hail Mary: Kecharitomene, A Unique Word for a Unique Lady


It was antecedently probable that the striking words of the Angel Gabriel’s salutation would be adopted by the faithful as soon as personal devotion to the Mother of God manifested itself in the Church. The Vulgate rendering, Ave gratia plena, "Hail full of grace", has often been criticized as too explicit a translation of the Greek chaire kecharitomene, but the words are in any case most striking, and the Anglican Revised Version now supplements the "Hail, thou that art highly favoured" of the original Authorized Version by the marginal alternative, "Hail thou, endued with grace". We are not surprised, then, to find modern translations of this to contain less explicit terminology of the chaire kecharitomene.
